# Need help with HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I have a simple class, called **Person**, as follows:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<PersonState> states;
    ...
}
```

And each **PersonState** is defined like:

```
public class PersonState {
    private Integer id;
    private State state;
    private Date date;
    ...
}
```

And **State** is a simple class, containing only an *id* and *name*, and I have all the mapping files configured and working.

I want to get those **Persons** whose last **PersonState** (based on it's *date*) has an **State** with *id* = 5 (for instance), so what would be the HQL query like?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p JOIN p.states ps1 
WHERE 
    ps1.date = (SELECT MAX(ps2.date) FROM PersonState ps2 WHERE ps2 MEMBER OF p.states)
    AND ps1.state.id = ?
```